# Load balancing: for Haproxy with 2 or more instances of the same services

Tags: load-balancing, haproxy, round-robin

I am having 2 instances of the same service on two different ips and using haproxy to load balance, each of the instance manage a session for a logged in user which is not shared across the multiple instance of my service.

If I logon on 1st instance with user-1 creds and user-2 creds on second instance, is there a way to be aware of the sessions active across the various instances of my service at the Haproxy level so that I can perform some operations on user-2 via user-1 like I wish to archive or dlete a user on the other instance but my instance1 is not aware of other isntances. Is there a way to solve this scenario in source or round robin with cookies balance algorithms?